# Автоматическое обновление параметров сети

Tags: сеть, centos

Есть сервер, с ОС Centos 6.4. У провайдера иногда пропадает интернет, и сервер не обновляет параметры сети, не получает IP и т.д, и поэтому его приходится постоянно перезагружать. Может быть, есть какой-нибудь скрипт, который будет при появлении интернета, обновлять параметры? Так как не обновляется сеть при повторном появлении интернета.

Имеются 2 сетевые карты, объединённые в BOND-инг (3)

**ifcfg-eth0**

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=0aa4aba2-e45c-4d1d-ba90-ca93cbaf071a
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
HWADDR=00:15:17:44:FF:48
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
USERCTL=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

**ifcfg-eth1**

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=e427aa5a-7e1c-44c0-8a2e-d5d7856e7142
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth1"
HWADDR=00:15:17:44:FF:49
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
USERCTL=no
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
```

**ifcfg-bond0**

```
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
USERCTL=no
BONDING_MASTER="yes"
BONDING_OPTS="miimon=100 mode=3 updelay=100 downdelay=100 use_carrier=1"
TYPE=Bonding
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

Comment: Что значит пропадает интернет ? Линк, шлюз, днс ?

Comment: Вот логи  http://pastebin.com/geqqVPvtСначала сканирует сеть по опред. адресу (172.23.127.253), а потом сбивается и сканирует всю сеть (255.255.255.255), и после этого приходится перезагружать сетевую службу

Comment: 172.23.127.253 а это кто?

Comment: Видимо наш DNS внутренний

Comment: У вас на этом адресе не поднят ли dhcpd, потому что, >DHCPACK from 172.23.127.253 (xid=0x59d9f40a)>bound to 127.0.0.1 -- renewal in 416 secondsВы получаете от него адрес 127.0.0.1 )))

Comment: Я получаю IP, я просто его скрыл. А так он правильный получает, просто время от времени пропадает интернет...и приходится сетевую службу перезагружать. Нашел в интернете, что я не один такой мучаюсь с этой сетью и в том числе с DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по содержимому приведённого лога, проблема, скорее, не у вас, а у dhcp-сервера провайдера (или у сети провайдера): время аренды, вероятно, что-то около двадцати минут, и когда, спустя примерно половину этого времени ваш *dhclient* начинает посылать запросы на обновление аренды, ответ приходит спустя огромный промежуток времени — минимум три минуты.

вероятно, время от времени этот промежуток превышает примерно десять минут, время аренды истекает, ответа нет, и *dhclient*, в полном соответствии с [rfc2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131#section-4.4.3) обязан освободить используемый адрес.

помимо первого приходящего в голову совета сменить провайдера, можно попробовать ещё несколько путей (приведены в порядке уменьшения реалистичности):

- прописать статическую конфигурацию сети
- запрашивать бо́льшее значение времени аренды адреса (`send dhcp-lease-time секунды` в `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`)
- заменить время аренды адреса (`supersede dhcp-lease-time секунды` в `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`)